# Trouble when adding https listener to AWS Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-acm-certificate

I am currently trying to **setup https** for my backend program (Spring Boot). My first step was to deploy my Backend program using AWS Fargate which gives a public IP in **http**.

Then I setted up an AWS Application Load Balancer for the AWS Fargate **using http only**.
This process was successful and I am able to call my BE program through the LB with a domain that looks like this: (The numbers and lb name in here are not the real thing)

```
test-lb-123456.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

Then I want to add an https listener to the LB, so I clicked on "Add Listener" and "Requests a new ACM Certificate" just like the picture below

[image: Add Listener]

Then when prompted to ask for a domain name, I add the exact domain that I mentioned above.

[image: Add domain]

But this request always fails with error

```
Additional verification required to request certificates for one or more domain names in this request
```

My question is, am I doing this correctly? Should I not add the "test-lb..." domain above when prompted to ask for a new certificate? If not, then what domain should I use ?

Thank You

**EDIT:** Apparently the images might not be displayed correctly yet because I am a low-reputation user, hopefully the images will be shown after review. [reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286362/image-not-showing-up-in-question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **can't get valid SSL** certificate for `test-lb-123456.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com`. This is because this domain belongs to AWS. To get HTTPS on your ALB, you need **your own domain**. You can buy it from Route53 or any external domain registrar.

Once you have your **own** domain, you can get a free SSL certificate for it using AWS ACM.

Comment: Does this mean that I have to buy another dedicated domain for my backend service then register this test-lb-123456.... to that domain ?

Comment: @Aldoaldo You can create a subdomain, if you already have your own domain, e.g. (`api.mydomain.com`). So technically, don't need a fully separate domain.

Comment: I see, last question, so after I created the (api.mydomain.com), I would then need to connect it to my load balancer, correct ?

Comment: @Aldoaldo You have to get ssl cert for `api.mydomain.com`, and also create alais record from `api.mydomain.com` to your ALB in Route53

Comment: I see, noted. Will try

Comment: @Marcin Just to clarify, 
My SSL domain name should be same to my ALB's , right?
Different domain name doesn't work ?